# AWS Sagemaker Lifecycle Configuration

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, data-science, lifecycle, amazon-sagemaker

I am working with AWS Sagemaker Notebook, now every time I start the notebook I should install packages I am working with like Librosa ( this one takes forever to be installed) so I look for a way to keep my installed packages in the notebook instance there where I found lifecycle configuration for instance and I have try every possiblity I found in net without any success always give long time error, please if some have a real good working solution help me, and thanks.

Comment: A simple option is to use EFS and install the library on the EFS. When you restart the notebook connect to the EFS and you can immediately start working.

Comment: Have you tried this page? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html

Comment: @Cecilia yes and it's taking to much time in the end error time out !!